# boosting with linear svm

Tags: machine-learning, svm, boosting, libsvm

I am working on boosting classifier. I am planning to use linear svm as the weak classifier. I am using liblinear for it.

My question is how can I weight each instance of liblinear based on the boosting weights?

Comment: how come you consider linear SVM is a weak classifier? It is much better than random guessing, doesn' it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple Matlab code using adaBoost+SVM, probably you can start from here...

```
    N = length(X); % X training labels
    W = 1/N * ones(N,1); %Weights initialization
    M = 10; % Number of boosting iterations 

    for m=1:M
        C = 10; %The cost parameters of the linear SVM, you can...
                 perform a grid search for the optimal value as well           

        %Calculate the error and alpha in adaBoost with cross validation
        cmd = ['-c ', num2str(C), ' -w ', num2str(W)];
        model = svmtrain(X, Y, cmd);
        [Xout, acc, ~] = svmpredict(X,Y,cmd);

        err = sum(.5 * W .* acc * N)/sum(W);
        alpha = log( (1-err)/err );

        % update the weight
        W = W.*exp( - alpha.*Xout.*X );
        W = W/norm(W);

    end
```

In [Wang's et al's Boosting Support Vector Machines for Imbalanced Data Sets](http://www.csi.uottawa.ca/~nat/Papers/29-Wang.pdf), they applied a slightly different formula in the weight update, aiming at dealing with class imbalance.

[Weights for data instances instruction](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/#weights_for_data_instances) is also shown in Prof. Lin's website.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I think in libsvm/liblinear you cannot give weights to instances. You can give weights to classes.

Comment: @user570593 In fact the link I provided in the answer is trying to give weights to instances. I didn't get a chance to try, but in their readme file, it says, -training_weight_vector: An m by 1 vector of training weights, where m is the instance number. You may take a look at the wgt weight file included as well. Thanks