# How to use svm for a large dataset to predict

Tags: forecasting, svm, predictive-models, libsvm

I am using svm method for prediction of wind power using windspeed. I have a large historical dataset containing timestamp, wind speed and wind power of size 6.74MB. it is a one year data at each 5 min interval . I am able to build one svm model in R Studio using 6 months data but it takes time to execute and if I try to use whole year data then program gets hanged. . Is large size of data is the reason for delay in execution? I am thinking now to make 3 or 4 svm model to cover whole year data so that all trends in windspeed get capture in resulting model . But the question is can we add performance of two or more svm models to get resulting one model. Please guide me , how can I get the resulting model with less execution time?
The Feature is wind speed and the there are 105121 data points.
The code is given below and i have ran it once only.
 sampledata<-read.csv("testdata.csv")
 index <- 1:nrow(sampledata)
testindex <- sample(index, trunc(length(index)/3))
testset <- sampledata[testindex,]
trainset <- sampledata[-testindex,] 
svm.model_4 <- svm(sampledata$power..MW. ~ sampledata$wind.speed,  data = trainset,
                   scale = TRUE,type = "nu-regression" ,kernel ="radial", degree = 3,
                   gamma = 1,coef0 = 0, cost = 4, nu = 0.5,
                   epsilon = 0.1, cachesize = 40, tolerance = 0.001,
                   probability = FALSE,
                   fitted = TRUE)
svm.pred_4 <- predict(svm.model_4, testset)

After running this code i am not getting any error . only the thing is if i take whole year data(6.74mb) in testdata file program gets hanged

Comment: Perhaps explain how many instances and features you have because 6.74MB does not really sound that large.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use [boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_(machine_learning)) with SVM. In R, [GBM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/index.html) package is available.

For more details, feel free to check out this post (same principle may work for svm): [boosting with linear svm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73526/boosting-with-linear-svm)

Comment: @KarelMaek I do not think this is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: And what is your understanding?

Comment: That the OP wants to (1) build multiple models such that building each model uses only subset of the data at once to save memory (2) combine those models into a single model.

Comment: This is what I am looking for@ DataD'oh. Because taking all data as input program gets hanged.

Comment: Would it help if you would export the support vectors from each machine and carry out training of a new SVM afterwards?

Comment: Another question: why you think boosting is wrong in this case?

Comment: Actually I don't know much about boosting.  I will read about that. Exporting support vectors from each machine and training of new svm afterwards looks fine. I will try this.

Comment: @KarelMacek boosting will still need to take in all the data so it will run into the same problems that the OP is describing.

Comment: @ArchanaDhanrajPawar can you please answer my comment to your question? And also add the code and any errors that you get to the question. That will help us to see what's happening.

Comment: The feature is wind speed. the data is available at each 5 mins interval.       The code is given below and i have ran it once only. sampledata1<-read.csv("testdata.csv")

Comment: The code is given below and i have ran it once only.               
 sampledata<-read.csv("testdata.csv")                                                index <- 1:nrow(sampledata)
testindex <- sample(index, trunc(length(index)/3))
testset <- sampledata[testindex,]
trainset <- sampledata[-testindex,]

Comment: svm.model_4 <- svm(sampledata$power..MW. ~ sampledata$wind.speed,  data = trainset,
                   scale = TRUE,type = "nu-regression" ,kernel ="radial", degree = 3,
                   gamma = 1,coef0 = 0, cost = 4, nu = 0.5,
                   epsilon = 0.1, cachesize = 40, tolerance = 0.001,
                   probability = FALSE,
                   fitted = TRUE)
svm.pred_4 <- predict(svm.model_4, testset)   After running this code i am not getting any error . only the thing is if i take whole year data(6.74mb) in testdata file program gets hanged

Comment: @ArchanaDhanrajPawar please add those details to the question and show the information I asked for, especially number of data points and features you are using.

Comment: @Karel Macek where can i get the coordinates of support vectors to use them as input for next model?

Comment: @DataD'oh I have added details to the question and also feature and datapoints. can you please look into that? Thanks